# Is there a way to preload an arbitrary number of parent associations in Rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, belongs-to

> **TL;DR:** I have a model that `belongs_to :group`, where `group` is another instance of the same model. That "parent" `group` can also have a parent, and so on up the chain. Is there a way to `includes` this structure as far up as it goes?

I have a `Location` model, which looks like this (abridged version):

```
create_table "locations", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "name"
  t.decimal "lat", precision: 20, scale: 15
  t.decimal "long", precision: 20, scale: 15
  t.bigint "group_id"
  t.string "type"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.index ["group_id"], name: "index_locations_on_group_id"
end
```

```
class Location < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :group, class_name: 'Location', required: false
  has_many :locations, foreign_key: 'group_id', dependent: :destroy
end
```

In other words, it can optionally belong to a "parent" instance of itself, referenced as `group`.

That parent instance can also belong to a parent instance another level up, as can its parent, etc etc. Elephants, all the way down.

What I'd like to do is string the names of a Location and all its parent instances together, so I end up with something like `"Top-level group > Mid-level group > Lowest group > Location"`. This is fine, and I've implemented that in the model already:

```
def parent_chain
  Enumerator.new do |enum|
    parent_group = group
    while parent_group != nil
      enum.yield parent_group
      parent_group = parent_group.group
    end
  end
end

def name_chain
  (parent_chain.map(&:name).reverse + [name]).join(" \u00BB ")
end
```

The only problem with this, however, is that it will query individually for each parent instance as it gets there (the N+1 problem). Once I'm including several Locations in a single page, this is a *lot* of queries slowing the load down. I'd like to preload (via `includes`) this structure as I would for a normal `belongs_to` association, but I don't know if there's a way to include an arbitrary number of parents like this.

Is there? How do I do it?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do that, maybe if you use something like Mongo you could embed document inside documents and all gets loaded at once but I guess you are using an SQL type DB. I guess you could try to add a new column with the model's parents' ids to have all of them with one query, but you'll have to maintain that column updated on any change, it's a way to prevent the N+1 problem.

Comment: Interesting idea, @arieljuod - this needs to be high-performance, so I'll have to check whether updating on each change is viable, but it doesn't seem like it'd add too much load. (And yeah, you're right about DB - I'm on MySQL).

Comment: If you were using PostgreSQL, you could do it with a recursive CTE (i.e. `WITH RECURSIVE`) to recursively join a table to itself. AFAIK there are ways to simulate recursive CTEs in MySQL but I don't know what they are off the top of my head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `includes`? No. Recursive preloading could be achieved this way though:

#### Solution #1: True recursion

```
class Location
  belongs_to :group

  # Impure method that preloads the :group association on an array of group instances.
  def self.preload_group(records)
    preloader = ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader.new
    preloader.preload(records, :group)
  end

  # Impure method that recursively preloads the :group association 
  # until there are no more parents.
  # Will trigger an infinite loop if the hierarchy has cycles.
  def self.deep_preload_group(records)
    return if records.empty?
    preload_group(records)
    deep_preload_group(records.select(&:group).map(&:group))
  end
end

locations = Location.all
Location.deep_preload_group(locations)
```

The number of queries will be the depth of the group hierarchy.

#### Solution #2: Accepting a hierarchy depth limit

```
class Location
  # depth needs to be greather than 1
  def self.deep_preload_group(records, depth=10)
    to_preload = :group
    (depth - 1).times { to_preload = {group: to_preload} }
    preloader = ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader.new
    preloader.preload(records, to_preload)
  end
end
```

The number of queries will be the minimum of `depth` and the actual depth of the hierarchy

Comment: You've defined those preload methods as class methods - I assume I could effectively redefine them as instance methods essentially by stating `records = [self]`?

Comment: Yes indeed, an instance method would be `self.class.deep_preload_group([self])`

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I don't need to do anything with the return value of this, I assume?

Comment: You're right. Rails' `preload` returns the preloader but you can chose what to return in case you need to chain. The `records` argument is a good candidate for a return value.

Comment: Confirmed working. I did some generalization as well so that this works for any association, and so that it can be used on referenced tables as well as just the current table. That's in a gist, if you're interested: https://gist.github.com/ArtOfCode-/8efd6417cdad7baa7c663f9f11edbf6d